# Non-static data member error with clang but not g++

Tags: g++, clang

**Summary**:
I have a [code snippet](http://pastebin.com/DGnfxmYe) that compiles fine with g++ but not with clang.

**Details**:

I have a project that compiles fine with g++ but when compiling with clang I get an error about `error: use of non-static data member`.  I tried to create a small test case that would demonstrate the problem, but for the small test case g++ gave the same error as clang.

I've posted a 236 line file to pastebin that demonstrates the problem:
http://pastebin.com/DGnfxmYe

When compiled with g++ 4.6.3 this works fine.  But when compiled with clang 3.2 I get the following error messages:

```
myhashmap.hpp:169:29: error: use of non-static data member 'num_bins' of 'MyHashMap' from nested type 'iterator'
          for (_index++; (_index < num_bins) && (bins[_index] == NULL); _index++)
                                   ^~~~~~~~
myhashmap.hpp:169:43: error: use of non-static data member 'bins' of 'MyHashMap' from nested type 'iterator'
          for (_index++; (_index < num_bins) && (bins[_index] == NULL); _index++)
                                                 ^~~~
myhashmap.hpp:171:17: error: use of non-static data member 'num_bins' of 'MyHashMap' from nested type 'iterator'
          if (_index < num_bins) {
                       ^~~~~~~~
myhashmap.hpp:172:17: error: use of non-static data member 'bins' of 'MyHashMap' from nested type 'iterator'
            _theNode = bins[_index];
                       ^~~~
```

Looking at the code, it makes sense to me why clang is giving these error messages.  What I don't understand is why g++ compiled the code correctly in the first place.  I did not write this code but I would like to get it to compile cleanly with clang.  So I'm trying to understand exactly what it is doing. And I would be interested in understanding why it compiles with g++ but not with clang.  Does g++ interpret the c++ standard differently, or is there some g++ extension that the code is taking advantage of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails with GCC 4.8 (prerelease) so I assume it's a bug that's been fixed. I can't find a corresponding bug report though.

To fix the code I think you'll need add an `int _num_bins` member to the iterator and pass the cotnainer's `num_bins` to the iterator constructor in `begin()` and `end()`, so it's stored in each iterator object.

---

*(Additionally, don't write `(void)` for a function taking no arguments, that's an abomination. In C++ a function taking no arguments is written `()`)*